# VSCode search and replace by removing the rest of the line

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code

I have several thousand lines of code that start like this:

```
'validated' => '2013-06-10 16:45:00'
```

or

```
'validated' => '2013-06-10 16:36:40'
```

It is never the same.

I would like to replace them with:

```
'validated' => 1
```

I know I can use regex to search lines and I tried this :

```
^'validated'=>
```

VSCode finds only one match and gives me something like this :

```
'validated'=>1'2013-06-10 16:36:40'
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this please?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `'validated' => .*`.

Comment: `^('validated' => )'.*?'` if `validated` starts all lines of interest and you want whatever is in the ticks to disappear, and replace with `$11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great resource for creating and understanding regular expressions:

- https://regex101.com/

Let's say we have the following list of strings:

```php
'validated' => '2013-06-10 16:45:00'
'validated' => '2013-06-10 16:36:40'
'validated' => '2014-04-12 01:59:24'
'validated' => '2018-02-01 11:22:01'
'validated' => '2020-01-01 10:21:00'
```

In Visual Studio Code, upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, make sure that `Use Regular Expression` is selected.

[image: Visual Studio Code Search field]

The following regular expression will select all fields you listed above:

```regex
'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (\d{2}:?){3}'
```

If the pattern occurs in other places as well and *must* be preceded by `'validated' =>` , you could add a `positive look behind` to the regular expression:

```regex
(?<='validated' => )'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (\d{2}:?){3}'
```

[image: Selected fields based upon regular expression]

All that needs to be done now is to click the `Replace All` icon on the very right.

Comment: You are assuming with this regex that something like `'2013-06-10 16:45:00'` does not occur anywhere in the file except after a `'validated' => ` part.  You are probably right but you should state the assumption explicitly.

Comment: Ah, right, good catch. A positive look behind might work in that case: `(?<='validated' => )'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (\d{2}:?){3}'`

Comment: Great reply, thank you to ALL OF YOU, Jason's reply is the one I choosed and it's working great.  Thank you agian.

Answer (score 2):

select any constant text like '=>' (select it as you select any text in an text editor using the cursor)

1. press <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd> (or right click and Change All Occurrence) then
2. press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> then
3. press <kbd>Shift + End</kbd> finally
4. press <kbd>1</kbd>